# How can I avoid in mysql that I have two null values on foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, consistency

I got a table `user`, a table `assignment` and a table `candidation` (with a individual primary, not the natural one) which  has foreign keys to both others. They are both 1:nc, means there must not always be a user for a candidation (user deleted) or a assignment (assignment deleted).

*Now how can I avoid having `NULL` in **both** foreign keys?*

**USER:**

```
-- Table `Ressource-Management`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ressource-Management`.`user` (
  `iduser` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `name_first` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `name_last` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `attendance` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `can_own` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`iduser`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**ASSIGNMENT:**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Ressource-Management`.`assignment`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ressource-Management`.`assignment` (
  `idassignment` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `owner` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `budget` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `priority` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT '',
  `date_to` DATETIME NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idassignment`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_assignment_user_idx` (`owner` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_assignment_user`
    FOREIGN KEY (`owner`)
    REFERENCES `Ressource-Management`.`user` (`iduser`)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**CANDIDATION:**

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Ressource-Management`.`candidation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ressource-Management`.`candidation` (
  `idcandidation` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `user_iduser` INT UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT '',
  `assignment_idassignment` INT UNSIGNED NULL COMMENT '',
  `date_from` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `date_to` DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `status` LONGBLOB NULL DEFAULT offen COMMENT '',
  `message` VARCHAR(4096) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcandidation`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_user_has_assignment_assignment1_idx` (`assignment_idassignment` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_user_has_assignment_user1_idx` (`user_iduser` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_assignment_UNIQUE` (`user_iduser` ASC, `assignment_idassignment` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_has_assignment_user1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_iduser`)
    REFERENCES `Ressource-Management`.`user` (`iduser`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_has_assignment_assignment1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`assignment_idassignment`)
    REFERENCES `Ressource-Management`.`assignment` (`idassignment`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: You could create a trigger on one of the foreign table `tableA` and discard delete if already the other one  `tableB` is `NULL`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza would need one on both of the table to be effective. _But.. I do not like triggers.._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A posibility is to create a trigger on the deletion, where I discard delete if already the other key is `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

if the only reason that leads to null values is a delete of a record, use logical deletion: add a flag `isDeleted` to both tables and make the foreign key fields in `candidation` as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: That is a very good aspect. Addidtionly I can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` to delete all three if I  want to do so.

Comment: it depends on the context. maybe it is a valuable information to know how many entry you delete so logical deletion is enough. also i would add fields to store creation and modification timestamps so that you can track when the record is marked as deleted.